E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ./tokyonight.lua
I'm new to neovim and I'm going through a configuration tutorial but when I entered neovim I recieved this error about the colorscheme tokoynight:
Error detected while processing /Users/<user>/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ./tokyonight.lua:1: loop or previous error loading module 'tokyonight'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ./tokyonight.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ...<user>/.config/nvim/lua/core/plugins_config/tokyonight.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ...rs/<user>/.config/nvim/lua/core/plugins_config/init.lua:3: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /Users/<user>/.config/nvim/init.lua:3: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Here's my configuration:
~/.config/nvim/..
lua/
   core/
      plugins_config/
         init.lua
         lualine.lua
         nvim-tree.lua
         tokyonight.lua -- tokyonight --
      keymaps.lua
      plugins.lua
plugin/
   packer_compilied.lua
init.lua

Here's my first init.lua:
require("core.keymaps")
require("core.plugins")
require("core.plugins_config")

Second init.lua:
require("core.plugins_config.lualine")
require("core.plugins_config.nvim-tree")
require("core.plugins_config.tokyonight") -- tokyonight --

plugins.lua
local ensure_packer = function()
   local fn = vim.fn
   local install_path = fn.stdpath('data')..'/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim'
   if fn.empty(fn.glob(install_path)) > 0 then
      fn.system({'git', 'clone', '--depth', '1', 'https:github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim', install_path})
      vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]
      return true
   end
   return false
end

local packer_bootstrap = ensure_packer()

return require('packer').startup(function(use)
   use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
   use 'nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua'
   use 'nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons'
   use nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim'
   use 'folke/tokyonight.nvim' -- tokyonight --

   if packer_bootstrap then
      require('packer').sync()
   end
end)


and lastly tokyonight.lua
require("tokyonight").setup({
   style = "night",
   terminal_colors = true,
})

I appreciate if anyone has advice or a solution :)
I saw that forums said something in regards to setting the configuration before loading the color scheme, but I'm not sure what this entails.

Packer is unmaintained. lazy.nvim would save you headaches in the long run.
